# Poisson model for non-integer

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, quasi-likelihood

I have a GLM with (quasi)poisson family.

My dataset has 3 variables:
rate_data
rate_benchmark
X

So fitting the model:

```
model <- glm(formula = rate_data ~ offset(log(rate_benchmark)) + X - 1, family = (quasi)poisson, data = data)

model_null <- glm(formula = rate_data ~ offset(log(rate_benchmark)) - 1, family = (quasi)poisson, data = data)
```

When using "poisson" it gives me warnings about non-integer values, which it doesnt give me for the quasipoisson. However, when testing for my beta being zero `anova(model_null, model, test = "LRT")` it gives me completely different deviance (hence also different p-values).

Which model am I supposed to use? My first thought was using quasipoisson, but no warnings does not necessarily mean it is correct.

Comment: Poisson and quasi Poisson both require integer response  variables. The warning message was probably not added to the quasi Poisson code.

Comment: Perhaps beta regression or Gamma regression would be appropriate for your data ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico That was also my first thought. However, this is to comply with national legislation. I have to test in a parametric poisson model whether my rates deviate from their benchmark with the regressor X. So perhaps I should choose the normal poisson.

Comment: @Eli Do you have a way to show he warnings?

Comment: If you're required to use Poisson, I guess you have to use Poisson. ...  I don't know how the function reacts to non-integer values. I don't know if it makes sense to run a test, say, with integer values, and then these same data, divided by 10, and see if the results change in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Overkill123, is your data supposed to be integer valued?

Comment: @Eli that could be. My rate is probably some fraction. I could maybe search for it in my data and multiply with the denominator to get a non-negative integer.

Comment: If you are able to convert the rate data back to counts, you can probable use Poisson regression on the counts with an offset to account for the differences in the denominators for the rates.

Comment: I see what's happening. The Poisson distribution is only defined on integers , but R must use the gamma function to evaluate the factorial in the Poisson likelihood. Since you can evaluate the gamma functions at non-integers, the model converges but R throws a warning to make you aware of the non-integers.  Your best bet is to convert your response back to integers. If you have a few non-integers that make sense (e.g. a machine reports 9 and 10 that got averaged to 9.5), you'll probably be okay keeping it even if it's not technically correct.

Comment: If you're scaling to rates, and then trying to fit a Poisson - even if you could succeed - means your variance calculations will all be wrong, and hence, p-values. You should change back to unscaled counts (which is what the Poisson is a model for) and use log-exposure as an offset in a log-link Poisson GLM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Poisson and quasi-Poisson models differ in their assumptions about the form of the function relating the mean and variance of each observation. The Poisson assumes the variance equals the mean; the quasi-Poisson assumes that $\sigma^2 = \theta\mu$, which reduces to the Poisson when $\theta=1$. Consequently, the deviance and p-values will, as you have observed, be different between the two models.

You can in fact run a Poisson regression on non-integer data, at least in R; you'll still get the "right" coefficient estimates etc.  The warnings are there as warnings; they don't represent an algorithm failure.  Here's an example:

```
z <- 1 + 2*runif(100)
x <- rgamma(100,2,sqrt(z + z*z/2)) 
summary(glm(x~z, family=poisson))

... blah blah blah ...

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.56390    0.17214   3.276  0.00105 ** 
z            0.43119    0.08368   5.153 2.57e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

... blah blah blah ...

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Now we'll compare to a pure "quasi" model with the same link function and relationship between mean and variance; the "quasi" model makes no assumptions about integer values for the target variable:

```
summary(glm(x~z, family=quasi(link="log", variance="mu")))

... stuff ...

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   0.5639     0.2621   2.151  0.03392 * 
z             0.4312     0.1274   3.384  0.00103 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasi family taken to be 2.318851)
```

Note that the parameter estimates are *exactly the same*, but the standard errors are different; this is due to the different calculations of variance, as reflected by the different dispersion parameters.

Now for the quasi-Poisson model, which will, again, give us the same parameter estimates as the Poisson model, but with different standard errors:

```
summary(glm(x~z, family=quasipoisson))

... more stuff ...

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   0.5639     0.2621   2.151  0.03392 * 
z             0.4312     0.1274   3.384  0.00103 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 2.31885)
```

Since the mean-variance relationship and link functions are the same as in the "quasi" model, the model results are the same also.

Answer (score 2):

The Poisson distribution deals with *counts* -- the actual number of objects you counted in a defined volume,  or the actual number of events you counted in a defined period of time.

If you normalized to a *rate*, the distribution is not Poisson.

Answer (score 1):

@jbowman said that "You can in fact run a Poisson regression on non-integer data, at least in R; you'll still get the "right" coefficient estimates etc.". I have tried this out and saw problems in the "etc" part.

My dataset is [mortality rates from Sweden](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0233384) , I have extracted the observations for females born in 1905. The resulting data frame contains 4 columns: `age` (in years, this is the predictor), `ndead` (number of people dying at that age), `N` (the total number of people in that age cohort) and `haz` = $n_{dead}/N$ which is the mortality rate.

First, let's perform an OLS with $\ln(\mathrm{haz})$ as the response variable to establish a "baseline", so to speak:

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(haz) ~ age, data = md)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.088305 -0.034501  0.000204  0.034399  0.075291 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.091e+01  6.900e-02  -158.0   <2e-16 ***
age          1.012e-01  9.136e-04   110.8   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04549 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9976,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9976 

F-statistic: 1.228e+04 on 1 and 29 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If I run a Poisson GLM in R using `log(N)` as the offset I get a very similar result:

```
Call:
glm(formula = ndead ~ age + offset(log(N)), family = poisson, 
    data = md)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.7945  -0.7639   0.1338   1.1044   1.8624  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -10.808320   0.052330  -206.5   <2e-16 ***
age           0.099560   0.000661   150.6   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 24739.939  on 30  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:    47.526  on 29  degrees of freedom
AIC: 324.69
```

Now let's perform the Poisson GLM fit using `haz` as the response variable. The parameter estimates are sort of similar to the fit above. However, look at the estimates of the standard errors of the coefficients: they are **much higher** than in the "offset" case, the residual deviance is unrealistically low and the AIC goes to infinity:

```
Call:
glm(formula = haz ~ age, family = poisson, data = md)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-0.0174605  -0.0048843   0.0008723   0.0071586   0.0212824  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -11.0679     8.9329  -1.239    0.215
age           0.1033     0.1084   0.953    0.340

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.1368277  on 30  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.0024028  on 29  degrees of freedom
AIC: Inf
```

From this I conclude that the Poisson GLM implementation in R (I used Version 4.2.1) cannot really deal with non-integer response variables. This is not surprising, because the Poisson distribution is discrete and "knows nothing" about ratios.

However... here is a twist to the tale: the Quasi-Poisson apparently can deal with mortality rates! Witness this result:

```
Call:
glm(formula = haz ~ age, family = quasipoisson, data = md)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-0.0174605  -0.0048843   0.0008723   0.0071586   0.0212824  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -11.067922   0.081368  -136.0   <2e-16 ***
age           0.103309   0.000987   104.7   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 8.296971e-05)

    Null deviance: 1.1368277  on 30  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.0024028  on 29  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA
```

Note that the parameter estimates and the deviance values are the same (within numerical error) as what I got from the `haz ~ age` formula with the Poisson GLM, but the error estimates are much more reasonable.

Since I don't know how the Quasi-Poisson magic is implemented in R, I have no idea whether this was just a lucky coincidence or it is supposed to work like this all the time. The safe bet would be to restrict ourselves to fitting Poisson GLM-s to count data only, because that's what the Poisson distribution is for (number of independent events in a generic interval).

Comment: I think this STATA blog post might be relevant: [Use poisson rather than regress; tell a friend](https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/). The trick is to use robust estimate of the variance.